# Critical points and Points of Extremum

Tags: calculus

Wikipedia says that:
*By Fermat's theorem, all local maxima and minima of a continuous function occur at critical points*

But I think that *all* local maxima and minima, *irrespective of whether the function is continuous or not, lies on the critical points* since a point where a function is discontinuous, it as also non-differentiable and hence should be considered a critical point.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that all extremal values of a continuous function occur at critical points.  It does *NOT* say that extremal values of other functions do not occur at critical points---it seems to say *nothing* about other functions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I feel the statement can be much more general by stating that *all* extrema occur at critical points for any function. I was enquiring if there is a specific reason for only specifying continuous functions

Comment: But the article is not *concerned* with that level of generality.  It simply isn't the point of that particular passage of the text.  In the context in which that passage occurs, *differentiability* is often assumed, so continuity is actually a relaxation of one of the common hypotheses.